# Переменная в bash скрипте

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Сделал простой скрипт массового переименования файлов:

```bash
#! /bin/bash

j=0;                    
for i in *.jpg;         
do let j+=1;            
mv $i  file_$j.jpg  ;

done
```

Скрипт переименовывает все файлы jpg в `file_1.jpg`, `file_2.jpg` и т.д.

Хотел, чтобы файлы переименовались в `file_0001.jpg`, `file_0002.jpg` и т.д.

Изменил строку `mv $i file_%04d$j.jpg`, но регулярка не работает.

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы работала.

Comment: Сформируйте `toname` как-то так -- `toname=\`printf "file_%04d.jpg" $j\`` и делайте `mv $i $toname`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

numfile=1;
for file in *.jpg;do
newname=$(printf "file_%04d.txt" $numfile)
mv $file $newname
((numfile++))
done
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: И `$file` следует обернуть в `""` на случай файлов с пробелами в именах.

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо за помощь.
От себе добавлю, что можно изменить переменную numfile на любое число и тогда имена файлов будут начинаться от этого числа.